# Using memcache with FastAPI not caching values

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, memcached

I am unable to get memcache to work with FastAPI for my application.

I am configuring memcache like this in FastAPI

```
def get_memcached_client() -> Client:
    return Client(['localhost:11211'], debug=0)


def get_app(memcached_client: Client = Depends(get_memcached_client)) -> FastAPI:
    """
    Returns the FastAPI ASGI object that will be later consumed by an uvicorn worker. This is where you register
    dependencies, route prefixes, swagger tags, and associate routers to the application.
    """
    app_config = get_config()  # get config and initialise logging
    app = FastAPI(title=AMS_APPLICATION_NAME, version="0.1.0")
    log.info(f"Starting {AMS_APPLICATION_NAME} version={app_config.app_version}!")

    app.include_router(home.router, tags=["home"])
    app.include_router(health.router, tags=["health"])
    app.include_router(content_relevancy_interface.router, tags=["content-relevancy-interface"])
    app.include_router(copperfield.router, tags=["copperfield"])
    origins = [
        "https://seo-automation-common-apis.abc.net",
        "http://seo-automation-common-apis.abc.net",
        "https://galaxy.test.marketing.abc.com",
        "https://galaxy.marketing.abc.com",
        "http://localhost",
        "http://localhost:8080",
        "http://localhost:3000"
    ]

    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

    app.middleware('http')(catch_exceptions_middleware)  # register global exception handler
    slash_patcher(app)
    return app
```

This is in router

```
router = APIRouter()
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_memcached_client() -> MemcachedClient:
    memcached_client = MemcachedClient(['localhost:11211'], debug=0)
    return memcached_client


@router.get(path='/content-relevancy-interface/get_locales')
def get_locales(memcached_client: MemcachedClient = Depends(get_memcached_client)):
    """
    Returns all available locales
    :return:
    """
    locales = ["en_GB"]

    cached_locales = memcached_client.get("cached_locales")
    print(f"cached_locales {cached_locales}")
    if cached_locales:
        return {"locales": cached_locales}

    memcached_client.set("cached_locales", locales, time=3600 * 6)

    locales.append("Dummy")

    return {"locales": ["en_GB", "en_ES"]}
```

This is where I call the application

```
gunicorn -c /etc/gunicorn/config.py seo_automation_common_apis.fastapi_app:get_app
```

When I hit the api I am not getting any values from memcache.

What should be the correct way to configure memcache ?

Any help is appreciated